In the Google meet API, is there a way to set the space title?
I'm creating Google meeting spaces via the meet API, and would like to be able to set the title of the space (seen in the bottom left of the meet screen). The screenshot below shows the title of a meeting which was created via a calendar event.
example image of a meeting space with a title
The title of the space is the same as the title of the meeting. However, when creating a meeting via the API, the meeting code (eg: "xyz-abc-yyz") is displayed instead.
In the spaces.create input, there doesn't seem to be a way of setting the space title (unclear if that's the proper term for it). Google calendar's events.insert|update on the other hand seems to be plucking the name of the calendar event (called the summary) and attaching it to the space that's created when nested conferenceData is included. Is there a way to add a title to an API-created meeting space without mediating through the Calendar API?

I don't know the answer but, one way to determine how it's done is to open browser developer tools when you create the meeting via a Calendar event and monitor the network tab for API calls. This will show how the Calendar app achieves this and you can then reproduce it from your code. It's possible that Google uses an undocumented|non-public API call for this specific functionality.

Yep, that's how I tracked down the ConferenceDataCreate api in the first place!
